# Surface Temperature + Air Temperature in Landsat image comparisons

Tags: landsat, heat-map, landsat-8

Quick question about relating Landsat Surface Temperature to locally recorded Air Temperature on a given day:

*Are differences in local air temperature captured by the Landsat ARD ST imaging process?*

*Would I need to adjust for those differences in order to compare Surface Temperature data over time?*

In the images below I have visualized surface temp. data from before and after a development with a high requirement for green roofs/ infrastructure (2006 and 2018). The locally measured air temperatures have a difference of 5 degrees celsius on those days, so I boosted the pixel values for the lower range by the difference in temperature. Although this skews the absolute data for the image, my thinking is that it should theoretically allow for a better visualization of spatially relative ST differences. Was this step necessary? Or is it the nature of ST imaging that differences in local air temperature are not necessarily captured in the process?

[image][image]